# problema com header Authorization node/angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Olá,

Estou tentando acessar um link externo a nossa aplicação, que deve ser aberto em uma nova aba. Preciso passar o login e senha no header da chamada, mas não estou conseguindo. Tentei a opção abaixo, mas não resolveu. Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema ? A aplicação usa NODE e Angular

```
var params = {
    Authorization: 'Basic myToken'
};

var url = ['myUrl', $.param(params)].join('?');

window.open(url);
```

Comment: Essa senha vai por GET? como é o código que a verifica no Node?